# Draw rectangle into different canvas in a bitmap in android

Tags: android

I want to draw a rectangle into a  different canvas using a bitmap, but my Paint class is not working.
Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in my code

```
public Bitmap createBitmap(Rect rectImage, int i, int j) {

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setFilterBitmap(true);
        p.setDither(true);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rectImage.width() * 2,
                rectImage.height() * 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);

//      c.drawColor(Color.RED);

        c.drawRect(rectImage.left, rectImage.top, rectImage.right,
                rectImage.bottom, p);

        return bitmap;

    }
```

when i use canvas.drawColor(), it works but my Paint class is not responding
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

```
Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bt, bt.getWidth(), bt.getHeight(), true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
p.setAntiAlias(true);
p.setFilterBitmap(true);
p.setDither(true);
p.setColor(Color.RED);

canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y1, p);//up
canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y2, p);//left
canvas.drawLine(x1, y2, x2, y2, p);//down
canvas.drawLine(x2, y1, x2, y2, p);

// rect ... 
//canvas.drawRect(/*all of my end coordinates*/, p);

ImageView iView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewPreview);
iView.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
iView.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: thanks but i have already solved the problem without drawing the lines

Comment: @PrabinByanjankar if you solved ypur problem then update your post so other can reference from it. and if other can also give a more finer solution if available

Comment: c.drawRect(
    new Rect((bitmap.getWidth() - rectImage.width()) / 2, (bitmap
      .getHeight() - rectImage.height()) / 2, ((bitmap
      .getWidth() - rectImage.width()) / 2)
      + rectImage.width(), ((bitmap.getHeight() - rectImage
      .height()) / 2) + rectImage.height()), p);

Comment: thing was my rectangle was not within the bitmap, rest are all same as above